# UWP crashes after downloading and installing from Windows Store

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-10, uwp

I have deployed my UWP application to windows store successfully. It rans perfectly in windows phone, however, when installed in pc / laptop from windows store, it fails and crashes.
checking event viewer (windows log) shows below error;

> Activation of app
>   AppName!App failed with
>   error: The remote procedure call failed. See the
>   Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

I didn't understand what kind of error it is?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you look into the mentioned logs? Go to Event Viewer and then to "Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\Apps\Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational event log"  Does it tell something related to your app? Btw. did you tested it directly from Visual Studio on you development machine? Does it work that way?

Comment: The application run perfectly while in development environment from visual studio 2k5. Here are the Log from the path you mentioned. ActivateApplicationForContractByAppIdAsUserWithHost of the app 35495AbdulRahmanHamidy.44059B86E89A8_1edfxrc5vntv6!App for the Windows.Launch contract failed with The remote procedure call failed..   Activation of the app 35495AbdulRahmanHamidy.44059B86E89A8_1edfxrc5vntv6!App for the Windows.Launch contract failed with error: The remote procedure call failed..

Comment: Do you really mean that you developed this in Visual Studio 2005?

Comment: I'm sorry it's vs 2015 community edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried yourself, with Visual Studio 2015, to run it on a Windows Phone device in Release Mode ?
Most of time, this kind of errors are due to .NET Native, which is not activated by default on Debug build but which is activated when app is published on the Store.

Thanks,

Comment: It runs perfectly from vs 2015 in both debug and release mode.

Comment: Make sure that ,NET Native is enabled. Project properties > Build > Compile with .NET Native Tool Chain. If you've migrated an old project it's possible that this wasn't enabled properly. LMK.

Comment: I created this project newly in vs 2015. I have checked that option and that's not enabled. Do I need to enable it for projects newly created in vs 2015?

Comment: .NET Native is activated by default on the Store so before submitting an app, you need to test it in Release Mode with .NET Native Tool Chain activated.
This will help you to check if there are some issues with .NET Native.

Answer (score 2):

Does your app reference a portable project? If yes, does the referenced project include resource files? We have encountered similar issues and they were related to resource files. Everything worked nicely when the app was manually deployed but when downloaded from Store, the app just didn't work.

Turns out the problem was with the resource files which were inside referenced project. The problem was solved by copying the resource files from the referenced project into the app's project.

Comment: thanks, I don't have resource file in my app. However, I have referenced SQLite for Universal App Platform and SQLite.Net-PCL and they are in reference section.

Comment: @ARH did you, ever get this fixed?